# CSS calc values computed differently on Edge

Tags: css, sass, microsoft-edge, scss-mixins, css-calc

I have this scss code snippet:

```
@include flex(1 1 calc((1 * (100% + (2 * #{$spec_grid_outerMargin})) / 3) - #{$spec_grid_outerMargin}));
```

In the dev console of Edge at my local machine this is translated to:

```
flex: 1 1 calc((1 * (100% + (2 * 1.125rem)) / 3) - 1.125rem)
```

while on a dev environment (same version as local) it shows:

```
flex: 1 1 calc((100% + 2.25rem)/3 - 1.125rem)
```

and on the dev environment this is causing a layout bug. How can it be that this snippet gets interpreted in different ways?

Comment: note that both are the same, the difference is that the second is doing the multiplication

Comment: Did you try to hard refresh it and clear the cache data? It can be possible that it is showing some data from the cache.

Comment: Could be a difference between sass compiler versions, or another package that is involved in the build process.

Comment: Cleared cache, doesn't help. sass compiler are the same.

Comment: But if I change the 2.25rem to 2.2rem it works. But it should behave the same imho. Really don't see the difference in the two layouts.

Comment: Problem identified. It was webpack that was optimizing the css and it optimized some needed braces away (only in production...)